# how to comparing two query on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry for bad english.

well, I have question how to comparing two query.
example.

tabel transactions

```
|id| name | total| date      |

|01|rini  | 2    |2019/12/1  |

|02|rana  | 3    |2019/12/31 |

|03|tono  | 2    |2020/01/5  |

|04|tini  |10    |2020/28/5  |
```

if I want to know transactions on december 2019 and januari 2020 I can write

`select sum(total) from transactions where date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31'`

`select sum(total) from transactions where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'`

but How can I compare between that 2 query and have result like this

```
|desember_transaction|januari_transaction|

|          5         |         12        |
```

sorry again for my bad english.
hope you all understand what I mean. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select 
sum(case when date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31' then total else 0 end) desember_transaction,
sum(case when date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31' then total else 0 end) januari_transaction
from transactions
```

Comment: wow, thanks man. its help me. but I wonder, what is function "else 0"? coz I put it on or not the result is same.